# SoapUI Project tests execution using Maven plugin in Jenkins transitive dependency error

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I am trying to run a SoapUI 5.2.0 open source project xml in Jenkins using Maven and getting the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test (SoapUI-Test) on project AmexIQCX: Execution SoapUI-Test of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0:test failed: Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0, org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.16: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0 from/to m-all (https://ci-repo.aexp.com/java-proxy/content/groups/prod/): Access denied to: https://ci-repo.aexp.com/java-proxy/content/groups/prod/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.0/jackson-databind-2.3.0.jar , ReasonPhrase:Requested item is quarantined. -> [Help 1]

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>AmexIQCX</groupId>
    <artifactId>AmexIQCX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>./SabreCommandLLS1-8-1RQ-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    <testSuite>TestSuite 1</testSuite>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>
                    <outputFolder>${basedir}/soapui-output</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>5.4.0</version>
                        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>wss4j:jar</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SoapUI-Test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectories>
                        <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/soapui-output</reportsDirectory>
                    </reportsDirectories>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/soapui-output</outputDirectory>
                    <outputName>${project.artifactId}-TEST-${env}</outputName>
                    <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Surefire-Report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: I see you commented out your exclusion elements.  I was going to attempt to solve this by excluding the dependencies from being added transitively, then adding them through a separate dependency block.  Is this not a solution you wish to entertain?

Comment: Thanks for the update. What do you mean by adding a block?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolve by using the following versions in dependencies with exclusions:

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
```